# How to have global SCSS

Tags: sass, jhipster

Im working on a Jhipster project and althoug i have searched for information about this topic i'm still very confused.

So my confusion starts by not understand why we need to have two imports of the same SCSS file:

global.scss

```
 @import 'bootstrap-variables';
```

vendor.scss

```
 @import 'bootstrap-variables';
```

I understand that global.scss is a way to provide global styles to the whole application, and vendor is a way for importing third party styles(SASS/CSS)

But if i declare a $my-custom-variable in global SCSS i will not have access to it in some custom.component.scss, but if i declare a class .my-class i will.

So my conclusion is, either i make classes on the global.scss based on some _custom-variables.scss, or i import my _custom-variables.scss on the component.scss it self.

The secound way seems like a hack and the first adds some labors.

Is there a better way hundle this kind of situations?